# Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR doesn't work properly

Tags: java, date, calendar

Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR doesn't work properly. My goal is every Monday was new week.  The results I am getting are in the code comments.

---

My code is:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
//cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(7);
//cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(0);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date d = sdf.parse("27/12/2014"); //SAT
Date d1 = sdf.parse("28/12/2014"); //SUN

cal.setTime(d);
Integer weekNumber1 = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

cal.setTime(d1);
Integer weekNumber2 = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

System.out.println( weekNumber1 );// 52 
System.out.println( weekNumber2 );// 1`
```

the second one:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(7);
//cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(0);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date d = sdf.parse("27/12/2014"); //SAT
Date d1 = sdf.parse("28/12/2014"); //SUN

cal.setTime(d);
Integer weekNumber1 = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

cal.setTime(d1);
Integer weekNumber2 = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

System.out.println( weekNumber1 );// 51 
System.out.println( weekNumber2 );// 52
```

And the third one:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(7);
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(0);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date d = sdf.parse("27/12/2014"); //SAT
Date d1 = sdf.parse("28/12/2014"); //SUN
Date d2 = sdf.parse("29/12/2014"); //Mon

cal.setTime(d);
Integer weekNumber1 = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

cal.setTime(d1);
Integer weekNumber2 = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

cal.setTime(d2);
Integer weekNumber3 = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

System.out.println( weekNumber1 );// 52
System.out.println( weekNumber2 );// 52
System.out.println( weekNumber3 );// 52
```

Comment: Date d2 = sdf.parse("28/12/2014"); //Mon is wrong Monday is 29/12

Comment: question is edited, but output doesn't chaneched 29 returns 52

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set Monday as the first day of week for your Calendar.

```
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

Comment: o yeah , I thought cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(0);(in my opinion mondey) was the same thing. tnk u